# How to write a lambda in Kotlin with multiple parameters of different types?

Tags: kotlin, exception, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

I am writing an exception handler for a WebClient response in Spring Webflux. I haven't included the code before and after my broken snippet to keep this short and sweet. Currently I have the following code:

```kotlin
.retrieve()
.bodyToMono(String::class.java)
.doOnError {
  WebClientResponseException::class.java,
  error -> logger.error(error.getResponseBodyAsString()) 
}
.awaitSingle()
```

I am new to Kotlin and the Spring Webflux's reactive programming. I can't understand what IntelliJ means by

> Unexpected tokens (use ';' to separate expressions on the same line)

[image: Code screenshot with error IntelliJ error]

The syntax looks correct to me for the following method signature:

```java
<E extends Throwable> Mono<T> doOnError(Class<E> exceptionType, final Consumer<? super E> onError)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a little difficult to answer your question, because it seems that the `doOnError` function your IDE is displaying is different from the one you've posted documentation for. After all, the IDE shows that the lambda is valid and has a single `Throwable` parameter, but the documentation you've posted requires two arguments.

If you just want to name the lambda paramater, you must do that right at the very beginning of the lambda:

```
.doOnError { error -> 
    // your code here
}
```

If you need to specify the first argument, you do so inside parentheses like you would for a normal method:

```
.doOnError(WebClientResponseException::class.java) { error ->
    logger.error(error.getResponseBodyAsString())
}
```

Comment: Both are valid as the `doOnError` is overloaded: https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html

Comment: @dominicoder thanks! I'm not familiar with that framework at all and was struggling to find the live documentation.